# Difference between name node and yarn in hadoop 2.0

Tags: hadoop

What is the difference between YARN and name node in hadoop 2.0 terminology? If there is,does YARN controls the name node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot differentiate between `NameNode` and `YARN`. 
`Namenode` has always been there since `hadoop1` which keeps metadata of cluster and stored data in the cluster.
`YARN` stands for `Yet Another Resource Negotiator` which is introduced in `hadoop 2` to replace the `jobtracker` and `tasktracker` of `Hadoop 1` with efficient processors like `NodeManager`, `ResourceManager`, `ApplicationMaster` etc. 
`Hadoop 1` was fully dependent on `Map Reduce` applications and that limit is overcome by introduction of `YARN`.
for more info see [here](https://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hadoop-yarn-background-and-an-overview/) and [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) and [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-1/)